# How to Modify "Authorization has been denied for this request." Using filter HostAuthenticationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token, authorize

Using Bearer token authentication. 
If response is failure then, need to return additional field along with below message:

```
401 UnAuthorize response
{Message: "Authorization has been denied for this request"}
```

How to include additional field in 401 response message.
It will be like as below: (include additional field 'ID' that indicate failure tracking ID).

```
{Message: "Authorization has been denied for this request",
 Id: 1}
```

filter.config is below:

```
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to include additional fields in a 401 response. Would it reveal something to hackers?

Comment: How to include field in 401 response. that response is coming from `HostAuthenticationFilter`. as its using bearer authentication.

Comment: What does the `Id` represent?

Comment: Its generated by backend to track failure.

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide your own implementation the authorization attributes by overriding AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class YourCustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            Content = new StringContent("You Message")
        };
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
[CustomAuthorization]       
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Also check this: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/customizing_authorize_attribute

Comment: I am using `bearer token` authentication using with filter.config, `new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType)`. If I include Authorize attribute as well then it would override the bearer token authentication.

Comment: What type of Identity server are you using?

Comment: Its oauth bearer token (JWT) authentication.

Comment: Similar to your answer, possible to override "HostAuthenticationFilter" to include additional field response message ?

Comment: I will double check

Comment: OWIN is startup and JWT is authentication type. HostAuthenticationFilter is allowed to validate request at owin middleware.

Comment: It should work. Did you try it? If it worked for you then you can change the response as you need

Comment: Let me try. Is `AuthorizeAttribute` and `HostAuthenticationFilter` will be same ?

Comment: this all time goes to HandleUnauthorizedRequest and return with failure response. Missing some stuff ?

Comment: After executing OnAuthorization , its not reaching to action method. this just respond with 401. Is missing here ?

Comment: If the request was not authorized, it will not hit your action method.

Comment: Actually, OWIN - tokenHandler class return with validated and allow to proceed further to web api action. But "AuthorizeAttribute" all time respond with "401". Have also overriden `OnAuthorization` and `IsAuthorized` though, it just return immediately after `OnAuthorization` and response with 401.

Comment: After this `Authorize` filter, its not going further for any filter or action execution. It just respond with 401. Expecting this to be go further to execute other filters and then, action Method.